# Angular is not running the change detection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I want to show or hide the button according to the value of boolean variable. And for that i am using **Output** property. But when page is initialize button is hidden but when EventEmmiter emmits the value then the button is again hidden instead it has to be visible.

> Parent Component.ts

```
showEditButton = false;

editButton(event: boolean) {
  this.showEditButton = true
}
```

> Parent Component.html

```
<app-tools-menu-items-open
  *ngSwitchCase="toolType.FILE_OPEN"
  [isTextEditor]="isText"
  (showEditButton)="editButton($event)"
></app-tools-menu-items-open>

// This component should be visible if showEditButton is true

<ng-container *ngIf="showEditButton">
  <app-tools-menu-items-pdf-edit
    *ngSwitchCase="toolType.EDIT_PDF"
  ></app-tools-menu-items-pdf-edit>
</ng-container>
```

Child Component.ts

```
@Output('showEditButton') showEditButton = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  uploadFile(event: Event): void {
    this.loaderService.shouldLoad(true);
    const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      const fileType = files[0].name.substring(
        files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1
      );
      this.redirectTo(fileType, {
        type: TOOL_TYPE.FILE_OPEN,
        action: 'file',
        value: {
          name: files[0].name,
          blob: files[0] as Blob,
          status: 'selected',
        } as FileResource,
      });
      this.loaderService.shouldLoad(false);
      // Emiting the value
      this.showEditButton.emit(true);
    } else {
      // TODO: Handle improper selection.
      this.loaderService.shouldLoad(false);
    }
  }
```

> Child Component.html

```
 <div>
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="options"
        (menuOpened)="setToolState(true)"
        (menuClosed)="setToolState(false)"
        class="icon-btn"
        [ngClass]="{ active: isActive }"
        matTooltip="{{ 'translateOpen' | translate }}"
      >
        <mat-icon svgIcon="file" class="app-icon-hover"></mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #options="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="openMyDocuments()">
          <mat-icon svgIcon="local_drive" class="app-icon-hover"></mat-icon>
          {{ "translateMyDocuments" | translate }}
        </button>
        <input
          type="file"
          #fileInput
          (change)="uploadFile($event)"
          accept=".pdf, .txt, .text, .epub"
        />
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="openOneDrive()" *ngIf="envName !== 'prod'">
          <mat-icon svgIcon="one_drive" class="app-icon-hover"></mat-icon>
          {{ "translateOneDrive" | translate }}
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="openGoogleDrive()" *ngIf="envName !== 'prod'">
          <mat-icon svgIcon="google_drive" class="app-icon-hover"></mat-icon>
          {{ "translateGoogleDrive" | translate }}
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
    <div #fakeHld id="fakeHld"></div>
```

Here i see that editButton is called but Change detection in Angular is not working.

Comment: are you sure `editButton` is called?

Comment: @Moshezauros Yes i checked using the console.log()

Comment: show the child component template

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: `this.showEditButton = true` should be `this.showEditButton = event` in your parent component.

Comment: I tried this but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ngOnChanges** Lifecycle run when previous value of the property is different from the current one.

```
 OnChanges(changes: any){
   if(changes.currentValue !== changes.previousValue){
    // white your logic here
  }
```

Read more about the [ngDoCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) lifecycle hoot